# Unable to launch google chrome by selenium 3.4.1

Tags: google-chrome

I am using `selenium version 3.4.0` and `chrome version 59.xxx`, `Chrome driver version 2.30.` Every time its shows error like-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:111)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:302)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:124)
>     at SampleTesting.main(SampleTesting.java:8)

Below is my code-

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Newfolder\\Selenium jars\\exe files\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
```

Please help to resolve my query 
thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Virendra, Were you able to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Guava` library version. An upgrade to 21.0 should resolve this issue.

Reference: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3880